# How to set eclipse to ignore the "Classpath Dependency Validator Message" Warning

Tags: eclipse, liferay, warnings, classpath

I would like it to have no warnings in my eclipse projects, but I get this one warning:

```
Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Liferay 6.1 GA Plugin API will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

from warning type `Classpath Dependency Validator Message`.

I understand what eclipse is trying to say to me, but that is wrong, the library exists at the server and it is not right to export this with my projects.

However, I need to set this warning in eclipse to ignore, how can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove it here:
Preferences -> Validation -> Classpath Dependency Validator

Also check if your specific project has its own validation settings overwritting the global ones.
Project -> Properties -> Validation

Answer (score 0):

Select the warning, press Ctrl+1 (Quick Fix), chose the option "Exclude the associated raw classpath entry from ..."

Comment: My all gradle tasks became disabled after doing this!!!! Now you have to tell me how to undo this?

Comment: @Khan I don't see how that could happen by following my instructions. Try to create a new workspace, import the project there and it should work again. If that doesn't work, restore the file `.classpath` from a backup or version control.